# How to load initial data from rails to redux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux

I tried to load json from rails, and pass it to redux createStore.

```
let initialStore = window.INITIAL;

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialStore);
```

But i always get undefined, or just window.INITIAL return value after store.

At first, store loads with empty object, then fetch action is dispatched, and i get updated store with json, but i already got error, when i'm trying to call something like { product.title } on empty object. No matter what I do, i can't load json before redux stuff begins, even with global data, like this.

```
(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/products.json', function(data) {
    return window.INITIAL = data;
  });
});
```

Api and controller is simple.

```
def index
  products = Product.all
  render json: products
end
```

How do you handle this? I want to do it without any gems like react-rails etc, i can't pass all initial state to Root component in one place.

Comment: Really crudely all you need do is just add a flag somewhere on `window.initial` such as `window.INITIAL.isFetching = true` then just change it to false when you've got your return data. This way you can query whether the data has been loaded and render a loading image or something until then ...

Comment: Why are you trying to pass data in to Redux from outside of Redux? Why wouldn't you trigger an action that fetches the initial payload? But anyway, if your data is fetched over the wire, you should also have an "empty state". The browser is non-blocking and asynchronous, so you *must* account for code requesting data before it comes back from the server; i.e. you cannot assume data is there if it's not loaded with the code.

Answer (score 4):

In the question above you have the following:

```
let initialStore = window.INITIAL;

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialStore);
```

The problem with the above code is that it will only populate your store with `window.INITIAL` as it exists when the page first loads. Any further changes to `window.INITIAL` will be ignored.

What you need to do is populate `window.INITIAL` with your initial data in your *server rendered* code. That is, simply place the script block *before* your redux code:

```
<script>
    var INITIAL = { /* this object should match the shape of your reducer state */ }; 
</script>
```

That's it. Now get rid of the AJAX call. You don't need it. This will be a lot more performant too. Instead of forcing the user to wait on an additional request *after* the page has already rendered, the user instead gets all the data at the same time as the rest of the page.