# How to edit default value in input form that we take from redux store

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, store

I have react component and inside a form with input type=text field.

In this component I get my values from redux store.I would like to take a value from redux store and put it as a defaultValue in my input field that I can edit and submit again. 
On new reload of the page it would take that value again from redux store and put it in input. Submiting works great but I can not get the default value working.

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <input type="text" ref="detailsText" defaultValue={details.details} 
   <button>Submit!</button>
</form>

handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {dispatch} = this.props
    const todoId = this.props.location.pathname
    const detailsText = this.refs.detailsText.value;
    dispatch(actions.startAddDetails(detailsText, todoId))
  }
```

Comment: put your full code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text input with default value in React/ Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890318/text-input-with-default-value-in-react-redux)